# How to integrate bootstrap datepicker with custom forms of web2py?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web2py

I am using the bootstrap form from ....
http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
but how do I combine it with the custom form of web2py?

Comment: please be specific... !!

Comment: I think you need to provide more information for us to help you.

Comment: instead of using the {{=form}} I am using the custom form of web2py using the form.widget.... now I have a datetime attribute in there.. I don't want to add the default web2py calender time.... instead I want the bootstrap datetime picker... Is this information f9 or do I need to provide more..??

Comment: Can you add the code you already have (or the generated html)?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is probably to define a [custom widget](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Widgets). Not tested, but something like this:

```
def bootstrap_datetime(field, value):
    input = INPUT(_name=field.name, _type='text',
                  _id='%s_%s' % (field.tablename, field.name),
                  data=dict(format='dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'),
                  value=str(value) if value is not None else '',
                  requires=field.requires)
    return DIV(input,
               SPAN(I(data={'time-icon': 'icon-time',
                            'date-icon': 'icon-calendar'})),
               _class='input-append date')

db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('myfield', 'datetime', widget=bootstrap_datetime),
    ...)
```

Then in the view, you can do:

```
{{=form}}
```

to get the standard form, or if you want to customize the layout, to display the datetime widget, you would do:

```
{{=form.custom.widget.myfield}}
```

You'll also need to load the datetimepicker module on the page and include something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('div.date').datetimepicker({
      language: 'en',
      pick12HourFormat: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: nope it's not working man.....it's just behaving like a simple string box.. !! :(

Comment: That was only the web2py code. Of course, you will also need to load the datetimepicker module on the page and then include the appropriate Javascript to activate the widget. I have edited the answer with a sample. Please see the datetimepicker documentation for more details.

Comment: utter sorry for the ignorance... !!
will implement this and come back to you... !!